# Changing image source property of a child with dangerously set innerhtml parent attribute in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, strapi, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have a Front end application which uses react and fetches data using API calls from the strapi backend.
I have provided a rich text field to the user in strapi backend where the user can also upload an image along with data as shown
[Strapi Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDuLV.png).

On the react side I am fetching data using API call with help of axios and displaying data as shown in the code

```
 const [data, setData] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
    callApi(the_get_data_url); // Calls the API and sets state using setData so now data field 
    //has all the data
     }, []);
```

This is a sample of what data variable will contain.

```
{
  "Subscription": "standard",
  "_id": "610bc1265aeb5e38e42c8220",
  "Headline": "How to stop screwing yourself over",
  "Description": "<p>How do you get on the road to being happier? Start by setting your alarm for 30 minutes earlier than usual and not hitting the snooze button. The effort required to leave that warm bed and enter the world is the same amount of effort needed to shake up your life and make that elusive change. In this humorous and provocative talk, Mel Robbins explains how turning off our brain's autopilot and demolishing our comfort zones is key to a rewarding life.</p><p><img src=\"/uploads/photo_1483985988355_763728e1935b_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxz_ZW_Fy_Y2h8_M_Xx8_Zm_Fza_Glvbnxlbnwwf_Hwwf_Hw_3_D_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_5186b4137a.1&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80\" alt=\"\"></p>",
  "published_at": "2021-08-05T13:06:47.325Z"
}
```

As you can see the Description field contains HTML tag as well as well as image tags.So what I am doing on the front end react to display this data is

```
<div id="description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data?.Description }}></div>
```

Now the problem is that image is not coming because its source is not fully correct.

```
<img src="/uploads/photo_1483985988355_763728e1935b_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxz_ZW_Fy_Y2h8_M_Xx8_Zm_Fza_Glvbnxlbnwwf_Hwwf_Hw_3_D_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_5186b4137a.1&amp"/>
```

Its correct source is in development environment **"http://localhost:1337/"+ source from strapi**
or for production environment **process.env.React_BACKEND_URL + source from strapi**
I have included Jquery for changing source of the image by
`$("#description").find('img').attr('src')` but I am not able to proceed further than this. Can anyone help me how to update the source property correctly. I have also tried the following function

```
import $ from "jquery";
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(CorrectURL, 3000);
};
function CorrectURL() {
  var images = [];

  images = $("#description p img").each(() => {
    var $img = $(this);
    console.log("The source is" + $img.attr("src")); // Getting undefined here
    return $img.attr("src");
  });

  window.images = images;
}
```

Comment: The answer is useful but my main concern is that why Jquery cannot be used with react. I mean Jquery has many plugins also which are very useful. I really wanted to go with some JQ way of doing it. Anyways thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just forget jQuery, especially in a React.js component. You could simply use [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) here, like this:

```js
let data = {
  "Subscription": "standard",
  "_id": "610bc1265aeb5e38e42c8220",
  "Headline": "How to stop screwing yourself over",
  "Description": "<p>How do you get on the road to being happier? Start by setting your alarm for 30 minutes earlier than usual and not hitting the snooze button. The effort required to leave that warm bed and enter the world is the same amount of effort needed to shake up your life and make that elusive change. In this humorous and provocative talk, Mel Robbins explains how turning off our brain's autopilot and demolishing our comfort zones is key to a rewarding life.</p><p><img src=\"/uploads/photo_1483985988355_763728e1935b_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxz_ZW_Fy_Y2h8_M_Xx8_Zm_Fza_Glvbnxlbnwwf_Hwwf_Hw_3_D_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_5186b4137a.1&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80\" alt=\"\"></p><p>Yet another image for fun <img src=\"/uploads/photo_1483985988355_763728e1935b_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxz_ZW_Fy_Y2h8_M_Xx8_Zm_Fza_Glvbnxlbnwwf_Hwwf_Hw_3_D_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_5186b4137a.1&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80\" alt=\"\"></p>",
  "published_at": "2021-08-05T13:06:47.325Z"
}

function addHost(str, host) {
  return str.replaceAll('src=\"/uploads', `src=\"${host}/uploads`)
}

console.log(addHost(data.Description, 'https://images.example.com'))
```

Or [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `Description` at the `uploads` substring to an array and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them again by adding the host:

```js
let data = {
  "Subscription": "standard",
  "_id": "610bc1265aeb5e38e42c8220",
  "Headline": "How to stop screwing yourself over",
  "Description": "<p>How do you get on the road to being happier? Start by setting your alarm for 30 minutes earlier than usual and not hitting the snooze button. The effort required to leave that warm bed and enter the world is the same amount of effort needed to shake up your life and make that elusive change. In this humorous and provocative talk, Mel Robbins explains how turning off our brain's autopilot and demolishing our comfort zones is key to a rewarding life.</p><p><img src=\"/uploads/photo_1483985988355_763728e1935b_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxz_ZW_Fy_Y2h8_M_Xx8_Zm_Fza_Glvbnxlbnwwf_Hwwf_Hw_3_D_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_5186b4137a.1&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80\" alt=\"\"></p><p>Yet another image for fun <img src=\"/uploads/photo_1483985988355_763728e1935b_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxz_ZW_Fy_Y2h8_M_Xx8_Zm_Fza_Glvbnxlbnwwf_Hwwf_Hw_3_D_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_5186b4137a.1&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80\" alt=\"\"></p>",
  "published_at": "2021-08-05T13:06:47.325Z"
}

function addHost(str, host) {
  return str.split('src=\"/uploads').join(`src=\"${host}/uploads`)
}

console.log(addHost(data.Description, 'https://images.example.com'))
```

I would probably add the host to the `Description` property in the `useEffect` hook (although I'm not sure how your `callApi()` works).